# How do you pass data from one text field to another when using Storyboards in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I am using storyboards for the 1st time, and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong here ... I have a button that transitions from one view controller to another using StoryBoards (the 2nd view is presented modally).

I am trying to use the "prepare for segue" in order to pass the value of a text field from view 1 to view 2, but it is not working. Can somebody tell me what I have wrong here ... ?

View 1:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"saveGame"]) {

        statsViewController *svc = (statsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [svc setStatsTextField:gameTextField];
    }  
}
```

If there is other code I can post to clarify please let me know.

(for the record there are no errors, the text field on view 2 just doesn't update.)

Comment: You might like this [extremely, extensively and thoroughly explained tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text field is probably nil at that point since the view hasn't been loaded. You can force this (no problem doing so since its about to happen anyway!) by wrapping your code in an if statement:

```
if (svc.view)
    svc.textfield.text = @"Hello";
```

Accessing the view property forces the view controller to load the view, if it is not already present.

I notice you seem to be passing a whole textfield object instead of a string to the text property - that doesn't seem like a good idea. It should be more like my example above.

Comment: Bingo- Set svc.textField.text = currentVCTextField.text after wrapping it in the if() and it worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just assign a text field in one view controller to a property in another one. This achieves nothing for the text field that is actually in the second view controller's view. Instead, you have to assign a value to the text field's `text` property. (And ideally, this value should not come directly from another text field because you shouldn't use views to store your app's data. Whenever a text field updates, you should store the updated value in a variable in your view controller or model.)

Also, the `statsTextField` does not yet exist at the time this code is executed because the destination view controller's view is not yet loaded. You should declare a separate string property in `statsViewController` (class names should begin with a capital letter btw) and then assign the text field's value in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: +1, the actual reason why it doesn't update is because of the use of `destinationViewController`. And of course, many solutions are possible...

Comment: I did the string property thing until I saw (on here somewhere) that you could force the view to load by accessing the view property. Can you see any drawbacks in that method?

Comment: Well, I think forcing the view to load in this way does not make for very clean code. The code does more than it says and would need a comment to make its purpose clear. And since you _must not_ use views (such as text fields) for the storage of your data (remember that views can be unloaded when memory warnings come in), you need the extra property anyway. In addition, it could be said that accessing another view controller's text field from the outside breaks the encapsulation principle. Only the view controller itself should manage its own views.